# Increment by 1 the last number in a directory?

Tags: bash

I want to increment the last number in a directory passed as a string with the following structure.

An example string that would be passed is this: `/efs/etc/alex15_0`

After the function is done it will become `/efs/etc/alex15_1`

The number I want to be incremented is always after the `_` symbol which only occurs once, it can be used as an index I suppose. It will be incremented by 1 no decimals just regular whole numbers.

I tried grabbing the last character using

```
${str:$i:1}
```

But that obviously would not work for cases like 99 which would turn into 910

In Java, I would grab the index of '_' then substring to length from that index and increment it.

```
str=/efs/etc/alex15_0
 updateVer()
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
$ str=/efs/etc/alex15_0
$ echo ${str%_*}_$((${str##*_}+1))
/efs/etc/alex15_1
```

The way this works is by using 3 features of bash:

1. **Remove matching prefix pattern.** `${pattern%word}` This is used to remove the final number and keep the head of the string.

   > The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the `%` case) or the longest matching pattern (the `%%` case) deleted.
2. **Remove matching prefix pattern:**  `${parameter##word}` This is used to give the final number after the <underscore>-character.

   > The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches the beginning of the value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded
   >             value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the `#` case) or the longest matching pattern (the `##` case) deleted.
3. **Arithmetic Expansion**

   > Arithmetic expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic expression and the substitution of the result.  The format for arithmetic expansion is:
   >
   > ```
   > $((expression))
   > ```

Comment: @DDisciple I did a small update for multi-digit numbers

Answer (score 2):

All bash without extended globbing, in case it helps someone.

```
echo ${dir%${dir##*_}}$((${dir##*_}+1))
```

Yes, you *can* use a parameter expansion as the modifier to a parameter expansion.

```
$: dir=/efs/etc/alex15_0
$: echo ${dir##*_}        # remove everything up to last underscore
0
$: echo ${dir%${dir##*_}} # remove everything *after* "everything after the last underscore"
/efs/etc/alex15_
$: echo $((${dir##*_}+1)) # show everything after last _, +1
1
$: echo ${dir%${dir##*_}}$((${dir##*_}+1)) # stack it all together
/efs/etc/alex15_1
```

Basically the same as kvantour's solution, just playing with layered expansions. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with `awk` try following.

```
echo "$val" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {$NF+=1} 1'
```